# How to get specific data table based when url id places on browser address without login

Tags: php, mysql

i'm a new and just learn and i have a confused to get data table from table to url id,
i want to get data from table when i write url for example **localhost/index.php?=user='username'** and table will show based on url username

here the table sample

**content Table**

```
code_content    |  judul_content  |  deskripsi  |  nama_lengkap
   2                  abc               tes1        john
   3                  efg               tes2        gerald
   4                  hij               tes3        john
```

**user table**

```
username   |  password  | nama_lengkap
 user1          123         john 
 user2          234        gerald
```

When i write this url **localhost/index.php?=user=user2** and I want this output to display

**

```
judul_content = "efg" 
nama_lengkap  = "gerald"
```

**

```
<?php 
    $koneksi = mysql_connect("localhost","root","1234");
    mysql_select_db("my_db");
    $hal = 0;
    if(isset($_GET['page'])){
        $page = $_GET['page'];
    }else{
        $page = 1;
    }

    $limit = 2;
    $offset = ($page - 1)*$limit;   
    $hasil = mysql_query("select * from content order by code_content desc limit $offset,$limit;");
    $get_total = mysql_query("select count(*) as total from content");
    $total_artikel = 0;
    while($h_total = mysql_fetch_array($get_total)){
        $total_artikel = $h_total['total'];
    }   
    $total_page = ceil($total_artikel/$limit);
?>

        <?php while($data = mysql_fetch_array($hasil)){ ?>

           <h2><a href="index.php?page=full&kode=<?php echo $data["code_content"]; ?>" style="text-decoration:none;">
           <?php echo $data["judul_content"]; ?></a></h2>            
            <?php echo $data["tanggal"]; ?> by <a href="#" target="_blank"><?php echo $data["nama_lengkap"]; ?></a>            
      <div id="posts-list" class="cf">
                <div class="right" style="float:left; text-align:justify; width:100%;">
                    <?php 
                        echo implode(array_slice(explode(" ",$data["content"]),0,75)," ").".....";
                    ?><br /><br />
                    <a href="index.php?page=full&kode=<?php echo $data["code_content"]; ?>">Continue reading...</a> <!--| <a href="#">Comments (60)</a>-->
                </div>                
                <div class="cleaner"></div>
            </div>            
                <?php } ?>  
        <div>
            <?php if($page > 1){ ?>
```

how to show table based on url user without login
Thanks

Comment: I do not see a question. Also, when I write a question, I try to give a title that people can search for that problem. Though, sometimes that is not possible.

Comment: and question marks(????) help us to find the question quickly

Comment: should i change the table ?

Comment: i add with how to .. is it ok ?

Comment: url should be `/index.php?user=user2`

Comment: @Zein You should give more information, like what RDBMS (mysql/postgre) are you using, any experimental code..

Comment: @ GotchaRob i use php mysql

Comment: `index.php?user=name` and you will find the name by `$_GET['user']` in index.php. Based on that you can build the table. I am still clueless about the domain and the range of your program.

Comment: i edit and place my experimental in above question but my experimental above not get username

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to retrieve data from 2 tables then you have to make a relation (Pass user_id in contents as foreign key) between both tables and then you can retrieve the data easily with the help of passed value by URL.

#### users table

```
id | username   |  password  | nama_lengkap
1    user1          123         john 
2    user2          234        gerald
```

#### contents Table

```
user_id | kode_content    |  judul_content  |  deskripsi  |  nama_lengkap
  1         2                  abc               tes1        john
  2         3                  efg               tes2        gerald
```

#### localhost/index.php?=user='username'

```
if(isset($_GET['user'])) {
   $user_name = $_GET['user'];

 $check_user = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE username = '$user_name' LIMIT 1";
 if(!empty($check_user))
 {
   $user_data = "SELECT contents.judul_content, users.nama_lengkap
   FROM users
   INNER JOIN contents
   ON users.id=contents.user_id 
   WHERE users.username = '$check_user'";
   print_r ($user_data);
  }else{
   echo "No User Found."
  }

}
```

Comment: in my table user there is no user_id column

Comment: user_id in content table i got NULL no id from user table... is it ok ?

Comment: No, user_id should not be null

Comment: When i type url index.php?user=username the result are SELECT content.judul_content, userapp.nama_lengkap FROM userapp INNER JOIN content ON userapp.kode_user=content.content_id WHERE userapp.username = 'SELECT username FROM userapp WHERE username = 'nama' LIMIT 1'

Comment: i just got it with some change to query and another script combine with your query above ... thanks for your help...